# SSRS,IBM DB2 -Number of host variables not valid in query

Tags: reporting-services, db2

I have an SSRS Report which is getting data from AS400 Database. The query I used in the datasource is a UNION of two queries.

```
SELECT        'SOLD' AS STATUS, SLSMCD, SLYEAR, SLMONTH, SUM(SLDLVQT) + SUM(SLADVQT) - SUM(SLDLVQTC) - SUM(SLADVQTC) AS TotalDlvr
FROM            VEHICLE.VHTSALSUM
WHERE        (SLFRAN = ?) AND (SLBRCD = ?) AND (SLDPCD = ?) AND (SLSMCD = ?) AND (SLYEAR IN (?, ?, ?))
GROUP BY SLSMCD, SLYEAR, SLMONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT        'TARGET' AS STATUS, STGTCODE AS SLSMCD, STGTYEAR AS SLYEAR, STGTMONTH AS SLMONTH, STGTUNIT AS TotalDlvr
FROM            VEHICLE.VHTSALETGT
WHERE        STGTFRAN = ? AND STGTDPCD = ? AND STGTCODE = ? AND STGTYEAR IN (?) AND STGTTYPE = 'EXEC'
```

on running the query I get the error

> "Number of host variables in not valid"
>   The number of host variables is not same as the number of parameter markers specified in the sql statement

I copied the query in AS400 and gave the parameters the query is running successfully.

In SSRS I removed the? and put the parameters values and it is working successfully. But if there is even a single? mark I get the above error.

Comment: At this point, you need to isolate the problem to see if the problem is on the IBM i (AS/400) side, in the SSRS side, or somewhere else.  To do that, you can use Run SQL Statement on System i Navigator; it supports parameter markers (or at least in my old days).

Comment: I didn't answer formally because I don't have access to an IBM i to check myself.

Comment: "it supports parameter markers"  ,are u referring to the ? ,i had to use only ? when i use AS400, for  parameters when i use SQL Server as Database i am able to use @Franchise .The problem as far as i understood is with the use of ? ,as i had some similar queries with union and the same parameters in SQL Server and it was working for that .I was not able to solve the above problem ,so i made a view with the above query without parameters on AS400 and then use ssrs to get the details.

Comment: Parameter markers has different syntax depending on the client side, being the most common ?, and :vble.  In your case, I think you have to isolate the issue to determine if the problem in in the Db2 for IBM i side or in the SSRS side.  To do that, you can use Run SQL Statement on System i Navigator.  In System i Navigator, the parameter markers supported syntax is '?' If the query works in System i Navigator, you may concentrate on the SSRS side.  If the query does not work in System i Navigator, you concentrate on the Db2 side.